# Android search in custom actionbar view layout

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

I used custom layout from layout folder to set a `customview` for action bar.

The following is the code for actionbar layout.

**custom_actionbar_home_page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60.0dip"
android:background="@drawable/b_header_strip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search_btn"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingRight="15.0dip"
    android:text="Dreamrun"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="35.0dip"
    android:layout_height="35.0dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8.0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/search_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/love_btn"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_header"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/love_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_whishlist" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The following is the Activity code in onCreate method:**

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        Singleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext());


        View localView =          LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar_home_page, null);
        mTitleTextView = ((TextView)localView.findViewById(R.id.title_text));
        mTitleTextView.setText("DREAMRUN");
        ImageButton localImageButton = (ImageButton)localView.findViewById(R.id.search_btn);


        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) localView.findViewById(R.id.search_btn);
        SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);


        actionBar.setCustomView(localView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

My problem is to display edit text to enter search key word when I click on the `search_btn`. It should work same as search in from menu.

But in my `Activity` I am using menu file for action icons. I am using custom layout for `actionbar`.

Please give me a solution to implement search functionality from custom layout`(actionbar)` without menu file.

Thanks.

Comment: What you wanna achieve is highly discouraged. Try using the new Toolbar instead

Answer (score 0):

you can't cast  'ImageButton' as 'SearchView'

```
final SearchView searchView (SearchView)localView.findViewById(R.id.search_btn);
```

see this [link](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/searchview.php)